# Am I supposed to wait 50 mins for this during Fedora installation?

Tags: fedora

I chose the option with media checking when booting.

```
[OK] Started dracut initqueue hook.
        Starting dracut pre-mount hook...
[OK] Started dracut pre-mount hook.
[***] A start job is running for /dev/mapper/live-rw(1min 10 s / 50min)
```

Comment: That message is just telling you the timeout, i.e., how long before the system will give up on that job, presuming it to have hung. Ideally it should take nowhere near 50 minutes.

Comment: @derobert IMO, your comment is pretty much an answer.